# Can we do modulus switching for number theoretic encryption?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Can we do modulus switching for number theoretic encryption such as Paillier or ElGamal?

Comment: In theory I *guess* you could, but what would be the purpose of it?

Comment: What is "modulus switching" ?

Comment: @fkraiem Just change the modular to a larger number. Like FHE.

Answer (score 1):

Security goals like confidentiality is the reason to ask for encryption.
Modulus is chosen (for particular group types) on the grounds of hard problems associated with that groups; encryption strength is defined by level of hardness of that problems.

It would be nice to discover a hard problem related to some change of modulus, comparable to indistinguishability of Diffie-Hellman tuples of 4 group elements for ElGamal or $n$-th roots for Paillier with modulus $n^2$.